# ASP.NET text box alert

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'd like to be able to have a text box alert in my C# web application if a file exists on a server.  Any ideas? New to C# here. So for example, if I have *text.txt* (and I know that it's always going to be *text.txt*) that someone drops into a folder onto a file server, my web application page will alert me using the timer (or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to check if a single specific file exists would be File.Exists:

```
if (File.Exists("c:\\test.txt"))
  //inform user
```

Comment: these work when you want to know if file exist or not.. not when you always need to keep on checking if a new file was created or changed.. thats What OP wants..

Comment: Sure, FileSystemWatcher is the way to go to get live updates. But I think that's not practical for web applications in most cases as these are request driven in most cases. For web apps it would be easiest to just use File.Exists while processing a request.

Answer (score 2):

Your web app is running on the Web server, which is probably in a locked server room somewhere. Showing a pop-up dialog there won't do anyone much good, because nobody will see it.

What you want is to show a dialog box on the client side (i.e., in the Web browser that's looking at your Web page). To do that, you have to use JavaScript; specifically, the [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert) function.

But now you've got a communication problem: your client-side JavaScript needs to be able to ask the server whether the file exists. Probably the best thing to do is to make a timer in JavaScript ([setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)) that sends an AJAX request to the server. You would have a "page" on the server -- some .aspx file -- that, instead of HTML, returns some simple code (maybe as simple as a "0" or a "1") that indicates whether the file exists. Then your JavaScript can load that "page's" content into a variable, inspect the variable, and know whether to show the alert.

As for how to do AJAX, you'll want to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Pick a library if you haven't already, and then read its docs to see how to do AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class for this purpose. But that has to run as a client application (Windows Forms application or a service), not from a web application (you can't access the client computer from within your browser).

Comment: Is there an easy easy to perhaps show on the web app that the file is there? Sort of like a listview or something? I need to be able to either see the file or have some way of knowing that its there within the web app and some guidance on how to do that.

Comment: if you want to check if a file was dropped in your own server then sure you can again use FileSystemWatcher.. and when an event occur handle it and reflect change on your webpage..you can make an Ajax call to  do this

Comment: if you want somthing else please.. expain your whole scenario.. i may get an idea as to what you want to do.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Basically I just want to see if a file has been created on a file server, then alert me on the page through making a label visible or having a popup or something to that effect. I have an SSIS package that converts XLS to PRN and I dont have any way on the web page to show the user that its been transformed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string path = "C:\\TestFolder\\......."; // Path

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

 foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {

                if (file.Name == text.txt)
                {
                    MessMessageBox.Show("Text file exists");
                }

        }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: these work when you want to know if file exist or not.. not when you always need to keep on checking if a new file was created or changed.. thats What OP wants..

Answer (score 1):

```
// TODO: Read up on FileSystemWatcher

FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

watcher.Path = @"C:\MyDirectory";
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Deleted);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Renamed)
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);

watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.Filter = "*.txt"; // could also set it to "text.txt" or "*"

void watcher_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Zomg " + e.FullPath +" has been changed!!");
}
private void fileWatcher_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.OldFullPath + " was renamed to " + e.FullPath);
}
private void fileWatcher_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.FullPath + " was deleted!");
}
private void fileWatcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.FullPath + " was created!");
}
```

Comment: good answer but its an WebApp not a winforms app.. we dont have a MessageBox Class here.. he can show that on Client Browser using javascript like alert("new file added");

Comment: Posting code for "pushing" alerts to web clients was not the question. He asked for a file creation trigger.